# Tree structure to string representation

Tags: c#, xml

I'm exercising to xml logic and I've some problem about a simple conversion.

My structure object appears like a simple tree structure, namely a class with name property and a `Children` collection property of the same type. What I'm trying to do is transform this structure to simple string representation (xml nodes).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using a xml serializer?

Answer (score 1):

You can create XDocument or XElement using Link to XML or manually.

Some examples:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/creating-and-saving-xml-tree-using-linq-to-xml
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/02/20/xlinq-create-xml-from-object-using-linq.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the child object, override the ToString() method and simply iterate through the collection.

Override the ToString() Method:

```
public override string ToString ()
{
    return this.SomeString;
}
```

Each object will give their description:

```
foreach (var child in collection) 
{
    xml += child.ToString();
}
```

You can go even further by using XmlWriter and doing a more proper implementation or even using Serialization for the object (If the child represents multiple data items this might be a better solution).

(edit: formatting)

Comment: By the way I cannot achieve an xml structure..I would represetn xml nodes (open and close tag).

Comment: You can build your string to be in an XML structure. You can also create a new method called ToXMLNode() and have it return a Node. But again, serialization might be what you're looking for. It's hard to tell without knowing about your classes/application

Comment: Sure..I can use serialization..but my real goal is working with "tree logic" and build an xml string by me.. However, I think to have found a clean solution and I'll post it.

Comment: Well, I solved by own my implementation. Simply, I execute a recoursive function for writing all nodes and I preserve all nodes which contains node childs on a separate (temp) list. In recorsive, I check if exist a node in a temp list (it are ordered for how I've inserted them), so if I find someone, I modify my string with "xmlString += "Closing tag.."